# BHO Accessing resource in managed dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, bho

I've created my first BHO, an addon for IE. I want to inject a javascript file to the head.

```
IHTMLElement head = (IHTMLElement)((IHTMLElementCollection)document.all.tags("head")).item(null, 0);
IHTMLScriptElement scriptObject = (IHTMLScriptElement)document.createElement("script");
scriptObject.type = @"text/javascript";
scriptObject.text = "\nwindow.onload = function(){alert('loaded..');}\n\n";
((HTMLHeadElement)head).appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)scriptObject);
```

This works just fine, but I would like to use: `scriptObject.src` and link to a resource file I have added to the project. I tried using the RES: protocol but IE cannot find it. Am I doing this correctly? Thank you.

`scriptObject.src = "res://C:/git/addon/ie/bin/addon.dll/script.js";`

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
scriptObject.src = "res://C:\\git\\addon\\ie\\bin\\addon.dll/script.js";
```

Comment: I just did and it didn't work. But I have an error notice: `Cannot find custom tool '[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand,Name="FullTrust")]' on this system.` Even if I don't include the src. Also, what if I don't know the path to the dll?